# WPForms Product URL

Tags: plugins

I'm changing from ContactForm7 to WPForms. Is there a way to have the mailform link to the url from which they were sent? This is meant for product inquiries so the sales team can easily review the product in question.

Comment: Welcome! Questions about third-party plugins should be asked on their official support routes as those kind of questions are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and out of this stack's scope.